# Trouble using webbrowser module to open a Google search

Tags: python, google-search

Hey I am currently trying to follow along with a python script to do a simple google search, I am following [this person's](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YLj1kuSZWcU) code line by line in the attached video. The issue is that my code will open up a new tab and bring me to the google homepage but does not perform that actual search. The weird thing is that the search query appears in the URL but it does not do much else to acknowledge my search. Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

CODE FOR PYTHON SCRIPT

```
import webbrowser 
new = 2 
tabUrl = "http://google.com/?#q=";
term = raw_input("Enter search query: ");
webbrowser.open(tabUrl+term,new=new);
```

Comment: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YLj1kuSZWcU      here is the link

Comment: Hey sorry I am new to this website and I am new to programming I put the code in the original question

Comment: Actually,it does work on my machine.Please check if there is something wrong with your network connection.

Answer (score 4):

So here's the issue: When you enter a single word as the query string (say, "python"), your code works just fine. However, if you want to search for more than one word ("python webbrowser module"), you have a problem. Since there are spaces in the search term, there will be spaces in the URL. Some browsers and operating systems, like Firefox 28 on Ubuntu 14.04 (my current setup) will handle those spaces just fine. However, others may not. Look into using the [`urllib.quote()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib.html#urllib.quote) function to change any offending characters like spaces, commas, apostrophes, etc., to their URL-escaped counterparts like `%20` for a space.

```
from urllib import quote
import webbrowser

new = 2 # not really necessary, may be default on most modern browsers
base_url = "http://www.google.com/?#q="
query = raw_input("Please enter your search query: ")
final_url = base_url + quote(query)
webbrowser.open(final_url, new=new)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
tabUrl = "http://google.com/?q="
```

without the #. [Technically](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragment_identifier) there are not supposed to be named arguments after this hash symbol.

Comment: However, if you go and use Google, you'll see that they do exactly that.

Comment: Hey I just tried using the tabUrl = "http://google.com/?q=" instead but it only places the query in the search but does not complete the search though

Comment: I would also recommend using @MattDMo 's fix.

Answer (score 1):

Try this simple code:

```
import webbrowser
base_url = "http://www.google.com/?#q="
query = input("Please enter your search query: ")
final_url = base_url + query.replace(" ","%20")
webbrowser.open_new(final_url)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import webbrowser

base_url =
"http://www.google.com/search?q="

query = input("Please enter your search query: ")

webbrowser.open_new(base_url+query)
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: It's not different than existing answers.

Comment: The existing answer i tried it doesn't search the input content on Google it just place it on search baar that's it.